# Is it possible to create reports with Workfront API

Tags: attask, workfront-api

I'm new to working with the Workfront (formerly AtTask) API.  I have to create many reports for a dashboard that are essentially the same except for the Program and Job Role values.  I want to create a python script to cycle through and create the reports.  Is there a way that I'm missing from the documentation?  Something like:

```
Name: "{} Program Hours".format(programName)
Report Type: "Hour"
Filters
{ProgramID={}.format(programID),
EntryDate between 1/1/2016 and 12/13/2016,
JobRoleID={}.format(jobRoleID},}

Chart
Chart Type: "Gauge"
Color: Green Value = 100
Yellow Value = 200
Red Value = 300
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No this is not possible Reports are not accessible through the API and do not contain an endpoint exposed to the api. You can find all avaliable end points here. 
    https://developers.workfront.com/api-docs/api-explorer/